# Remove Source Mapping with Gulp

Tags: jquery, gulp, bower

I'm using Gulp and Bower to get JQuery into my project. However the jquery.min.cs file has a SourceMappingURL at the end of the precompiled file and I would like to remove this.

Currently my Gulp just copy the original file to the destination like that:

```
gulp.task('jquery', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.jquerySrc)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jqueryDest));
});
```

I found a lot of ways to add source mappings but none to remove. I would like to not recompile all the jquery just for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this:

```
const paths = {
    jquerySrc: './path/to/src/jquery.css',
    jqueryDest: './path/to/dest/'
};

gulp.task('jquery', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.jquerySrc)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/dev/null', {addComment: false}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jqueryDest));
});
```

You could also try the [strip-source-map-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strip-source-map-loader) package.  Never used either, but in theory both should work, maybe.

Comment: Works very well! I'd tried this but I missed the '/dev/null'.

Comment: in my system (osx) this creates an actual directory in the source folder called 'dev', and another one called 'null' within it.

Comment: I'm surprised that doesn't happen on every system. Robert McKee and @max-bündchen on your system does gulp treat the 'null' as a special non-destination, even despite the quotation marks?

Comment: @henry Not really.  `/dev/null` is a special device that throws away everything written to it.  DOS/Windows has a similar device `NUL:` or `\\.\NUL`.   Not sure why it is creating a folder under your source tree when it is an absolute directory name (permissions issue?), but I'm fairly confident that osx has `/dev/null` as well.

Comment: Ah that's what I get for not testing. I missed the initial `/` and don't know my nixes well enough. I see that OSX does indeed have `/dev/null`. Still haven't tested but I would expect it to work

Answer (score 1):

The [gulp-purge-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-purge-sourcemaps) package worked for me.
Here's what you would do with your example:

```
const purgeSourcemaps = require('gulp-purge-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('jquery', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.jquerySrc)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(purgeSourcemaps())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jqueryDest));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Being on Windows, none of the response here worked for me.
I have a different approach on the matter, but there is a trade-off: you lose all the comments from the output.

```
const stripComments = require('gulp-strip-comments')

gulp.task('jquery', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.jquerySrc)
        .pipe(stripComments({trim: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jqueryDest));
});
```

For more info: [gulp-strip-comments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-strip-comments)